# Are template class statics instantiated differently across shared libraries consistent in the final binary?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a couple of classes that act as a unique type id generator:

```
// <type_generator.hpp>
template<typename SK,typename T>
struct Component
{
    static uint const index;
};

template<typename SK>
class ComponentCount
{
    template<typename CSK,typename CT>
    friend struct Component;

private:
    template<typename T>
    static uint next() {
        return ComponentCount<SK>::get_counter();
    }

    static uint get_counter()
    {
        static uint counter = 0;
        return counter++;
    }
};

template<typename SK,typename T>
uint const Component<SK,T>::index(ComponentCount<SK>::template next<T>());

struct Key{};
```

Now say I instantiate the above class templates in different ways in multiple different libraries:

```
// libsrc0
uint const x0 = Component<Key,int>::index;
uint const x1 = Component<Key,std::string>::index;
uint const x2 = Component<Key,double>::index;

// libsrc1
uint const x0 = Component<Key,std::string>::index;
uint const x1 = Component<Key,double>::index;
uint const x2 = Component<Key,int>::index;

// libsrc2
uint const x0 = Component<Key,int>::index;
uint const x1 = Component<Key,std::string>::index;
```

Is there any guarantee that a binary that links against libsrc0, libsrc1 and libsrc2 will have a consistent definition of the Component::index indices, with each index set to a different value?

```
Component<Key,int>::index
Component<Key,std::string>::index
Component<Key,double>::index
```

Comment: Unless the templates are explicitly instantiated and those instantiations exported by a library common to all of them, I believe the answer is no.

Comment: I've just checked it for shared libs with GCC 4.8, and it works, i.e. `<Component<Key,int>>::index == 0`, `<Component<Key,std::string>>::index == 1` and `<Component<Key,double>>::index == 2` in all libraries, but I don't know yet if the standard guarantees that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any guarantee that a binary that links against libsrc0, libsrc1 and libsrc2 will have a consistent definition of the Component::index indices?

Yes. Static data members always have *[external linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage)*, which means the same name refers to the same object among all translation units. Static data members of class templates are not an exception. After all, class template instance behaves just like all other classes.

Even though each shared library file will have it's own instances of `Component` template and particularly `Component::index` variable, only one instance will be selected and initialized when loading these libraries. For example, I discovered that GNU loader under Linux always selects an object from the first library specified on the command line with `-l` option when compiling an executable, and all other objects with the same name encountered in other libraries are simply ignored.

Comment: Yes for Unixes, no for Windows. Import table of PE files contains list of modules with a list of symbols for each module, so global symbol search is not performed.